# R - pbkrtest, “Error : object ‘sigma’ is not exported by 'namespace:stats'”

Tags: r

I get the following error message when trying to load `pbkrtest`:

> Error : object ‘sigma’ is not exported by 'namespace:stats'
>   In addition: Warning messages: 1: package ‘pbkrtest’ was built under R version 3.3.1 2: replacing previous import by ‘stats::sigma’ when loading ‘pbkrtest’
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pbkrtest’

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your r version

Comment: okay, its only 6 months old, but still i would try updating R to the current version, and then try reinstalling pbkrtest

Comment: have a read of this.. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Updating-Package-Fails-Help-on-How-to-Fix-Needed-td4715459.html. So loks like you need to update R

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this:

```
update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.org')
```

It works for me.