# Error when installing mnlogit: "object index is not exported by namespace:mnlogit"

Tags: r

I'm attempting to install the multivariable logistic regression package mnlogit on R Studio 3.5.3

When I execute

```
install.packages("mnlogit")
```

The package successfully unpacks, but the installation fails and I get the following error message:

```
Error : object 'index' is not exported by 'namespace:mlogit'
```

I attempted to correct the problem by running

update.packages()

as suggested on this post, which dealt with the same error message associated with a different package and function,

[R - pbkrtest, “Error : object ‘sigma’ is not exported by 'namespace:stats'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635823/r-pbkrtest-error-object-sigmais-not-exported-by-namespacestats)

However, the same error persists, even after reinstalling mlogit, MASS, and other dependencies. Is there anything else I can try to correct the error and complete the installation?

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? What command triggers it? What version of `mlogit` do you have installed?

Comment: I get the error message when attempting to execute install.packages("mnlogit"). mnlogit loads, but fails to complete installation because of the dependency.

Comment: Wait, if you get the error during `install.packages("mnlogit")`, then how can you possibly load `mnlogit`? That shouldn't be available if the install fails. Something weird seems to be going on. What version of `mnlogit` appears to be installed? Perhaps you can be more clear about what exactly appears in your console when you run these in a fresh R session.

Comment: I misspoke. mnlogit successfully unpacks but the installation fails. I cannot load it as a library. The mlogit version installed is mlogit_0.4-1

Comment: That is an older version of `mlogit`. Are you sure you reinstalled it? The current version is `mlogit_1.0-2.1`

Comment: I'll try reinstalling it again, perhaps that will resolve the problem with mnlogit.